# TSQL Условия выборок . Удалить все записи для преподавателей, у которых не указан контактный телефон

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-server, сервер, ssms

Проект таблицы

```
Код_преподавателя   int 
Фамилия nchar(50)   
Имя nchar(50)   
Отчество    nchar(50)   
Стоимость_часа  decimal(18, 0)  
Контактный_телефон  nvarchar(20)    
Образование nchar(50)
```

Answer (score 1):

Для удаления данных используется оператор `DELETE FROM`:

```sql
DELETE FROM название_таблицы
WHERE контактный_телефон IS NULL OR контактный_телефон = '';
```

Comment: `WHERE nullif(контактный_телефон, '') isnull`